# for(;;) loop makes my applet unuseable

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, applet, freeze

Here is my loop class:

public class Timer {

```
private Timer timer;
private static boolean isRunning = true;

public static void gameLoop()
{
    while(isRunning) //the loop
    {
        try {
            Main.cash--;
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {              
            // e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
}
```

When I run the applet, I get a white screen, and I cannot close the applet, I have to use the terminate button in eclipse.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.   But for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

```
while(isRunning=true) //the loop
```

...sets `isRunning` to true, then returns true (whatever the previous value of `isRunning` was), and thus always executes the if statement. A single = is an assignment, which in this case is almost certainly not what you want to do.

You want to use == instead:

```
while(isRunning==true) //the loop
```

Or alternatively, more concisely (and also preferably!) simply:

```
while(isRunning) //the loop
```

I assume that `isRunning` will be set to false elsewhere in your code, because there's nothing that sets it to false here.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've added that now, but wanted to demonstrate the difference between single and double equals, since that was clearly the primary conceptual issue here.

Comment: I have it now set to while(isRunning), but I still get a white screen, anything else I should do? (Edited the question to include the edit)

Answer (score 4):

In your while loop, you attempt to compare boolean values with `=`, but that's the assignment operator.  It's always `true` and this results in an infinite loop.

Use `==` to compare boolean values.

Or better, just use `while (isRunning)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

First your using the assignment operator instead of the comparison operator in the while loop.

```
 while(isRunning=true)
```

should be:

```
 while(isRunning==true)
```

Second `isRunning` is never set to false.

These two issues cause an infinite loop.